# "No match for X" vs "no match against X"

Tags: word-choice

Hi all I was wondering if I wanted to say that a tsunami has no chance against a set of defenses, would I say:

1. This tsunami is no match against the defenses.
2. This tsunami is no match for the defenses.

Or are both acceptable?

Comment: Grammatically speaking there's nothing inherently wrong with *no match against*, and although far less common, [it does occur](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=is+no+match+against%2Cis+no+match+for&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3). But many people will consider it at the very least "non-standard", or even "invalid", so I would advise non-native speakers to avoid it completely or risk being criticised for "incorrect" word-choice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [ngrams](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=match+against%2Cmatch+for&year_start=1700&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=3) for *match against,match for* shows that *match for* is much more frequently seen in print.  The wiktionary entries for *[against](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/against#Preposition)* and *[for](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/for#Preposition)* prepositions both show about a dozen senses each, among which none seem to precisely match the usage in your example sentences.  It appears that technically you could use either form and be able to justify it by dictionary reference; however, your

> This tsunami is no match for the defenses.

will be thought more correct by more people.  Note, while "no match for" clearly places the  strength of defense above the power of the tsunami, the very-similar "not a match for" is ambiguous and could be taken either way, as above or below.  You might consider instead saying, *e.g.*,

> The defenses will easily withstand this tsunami.

Comment: I think *"X is no match for Y"* is a fairly standard idiom where there's no doubt Y will prevail. But things are very different with *"There is a mismatch between X and Y's powers"*, where all we know is it'll be a walkover for one of them.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, that's consistent with what I wrote -- that "no match for" is clear (not ambiguous).  Like you, I don't regard your "there is a mismatch..." phrasing as an example of ambiguity, because the "walkover for one of them" implication seems quite clear.  Whether my "not a match for" example exhibits ambiguity (as I suggest in answer) is perhaps less clear.

Comment: Yes, but your "in-betweeny" case [hardly even exists](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=not+a+match+for%2Cno+match+for&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) by comparison with the standard idiom. By contrast, *is a mismatch between* has [come to be quite common](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=not+a+match+for%2Cis+a+mismatch+between&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) over recent decades, even though superficially it tells us very little.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Ok, I see what you mean.  Mostly.  I'm having trouble with whether "superficially it tells us very little" means "apparently it tells us little but really it tells a lot" or *superficially* is a slight misspelling of *actually*.

Comment: Now, now! As the pseudonym implies, I'm a bit cack-handed on the k/b, but even I couldn't manage *superficially* as a typo  for *actually!* I meant *"from the perspective you and I are considering"*, which is basically *"Who's gonna win?"*. From the perspective of *"Is it gonna be a good fight?"*, you probably don't want to hear that there's a serious mismatch.

Answer (score 3):

The correct answer should be

> This Tsunami is no match for the defenses